# Al capturar error "pywintypes.error:" de da: NameError: name 'pywintypes' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

¡Hola! Estoy intentando desencriptar una variable con python (Por puros motivos pedagógicos, nada malicioso) que estaba dentro de mi base de datos login de chrome, la cosa es que al fallar al utilizar una clave me lanza la excepción "pywintypes.error:" pero al capturarla me dice que no existe, y no se como solucionar el problema, agradezco su ayuda, debajo el código:

**Mi codigo**

```
import os
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
import time
import threading as th

pase = -2146893813

def Uncrypt(dato, codigo, limite, nombre):

    print(nombre + ": " + "Probando con: " + str(codigo))

    try:

        liberado = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(dato[0], str(codigo).encode(), None, None, 0)

    except pywintypes.error:

        print("Entrando en el ciclo")
        """

        if codigo == 9999999999:

            print("No se encontró la clave")

        """


        if codigo == limite:

            print("No se encontró la clave")

        else:

            Uncrypt(dato, codigo + 1, limite, nombre)

    liberado = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(dato[0], str(codigo).encode(), None, None, 0)

data_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + "\\Documents"

login_db = os.path.join(data_path, 'Login Data')

c = sqlite3.connect(login_db)

cursor = c.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT password_value FROM logins")

claves = cursor.fetchone()

c.close()

th.Thread(target = Uncrypt, args =(claves, -2146893813, -2146800000, "Hilo 1",)).start()

th.Thread(target = Uncrypt, args =(claves, -2146800000, -1146800000, "Hilo 2",)).start()
```

**El error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Aixa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "C:\Users\Aixa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "Descriptar base de datos.py", line 17, in Uncrypt
   except pywintypes.error:
NameError: name 'pywintypes' is not defined
```

**PD: estoy usando 2 hilos para mejorar el rendimiento**

Comment: Importa el módulo, `import pywintypes` antes.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió